# Convert Boolean to String with Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

What is the easiest way to convert a Boolean value into a String in an Inno Setup Pascal script? This trivial task that should be completely implicit seems to require a full-blown `if`/`else` construction.

```pascal
function IsDowngradeUninstall: Boolean;
begin
    Result := IsCommandLineParamSet('downgrade');
    MsgBox('IsDowngradeUninstall = ' + Result, mbInformation, MB_OK);
end;
```

This doesn't work because "Type mismatch". `IntToStr` doesn't accept a `Boolean` neither. `BoolToStr` does not exist.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you need it once only, the easiest inline solution is to cast the `Boolean` to `Integer` and use the [`IntToStr` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_inttostr). You get `1` for `True` and `0` for `False`.

```pascal
MsgBox('IsDowngradeUninstall = ' + IntToStr(Integer(Result)), mbInformation, MB_OK);
```

Though, I usually use the [`Format` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_format) for the same result:

```pascal
MsgBox(Format('IsDowngradeUninstall = %d', [Result]), mbInformation, MB_OK);
```

(Contrary to Delphi) The Inno Setup/Pascal Script `Format` implicitly converts the `Boolean` to `Integer` for `%d`.

---

If you need a more fancy conversion, or if you need the conversion often, implement your own function, as @RobeN already shows in his answer.

```pascal
function BoolToStr(Value: Boolean): String; 
begin
  if Value then
    Result := 'Yes'
  else
    Result := 'No';
end;
```

Answer (score 8):

```
[Code]
function BoolToStr(Value : Boolean) : String; 
begin
  if Value then
    result := 'true'
  else
    result := 'false';
end;
```

or

```
[Code]
function IsDowngradeUninstall: Boolean;
begin
    Result := IsCommandLineParamSet('downgrade');
    if Result then 
      MsgBox('IsDowngradeUninstall = True', mbInformation, MB_OK)
    else
      MsgBox('IsDowngradeUninstall = False', mbInformation, MB_OK);
end;
```